# WPF Label vs TextBlock in Border?

Tags: wpf, label, border

If you know that you have to **show tens of texts with a border**, 
would you decide for a 
`Label` (which is much complex and resources consuming) 
or a 
`TextBlock` in a `Border`? .

The performance aspect is the one interesting for me now.

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Label and TextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382925/difference-between-label-and-textblock)  Even the accepted answer just refers to another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the answer given here:

[What is the difference between the WPF TextBlock element and Label control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wpf-textblock-element-and-label-control)