# Difference between Label and TextBlock

Tags: wpf, label, textblock

According to the [Windows Applications Development with Microsoft .NET 4 70-511](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-511&locale=en-us) Training Kit

What is the difference between the `Label` control and `TextBlock` control since both are content controls and just displaying text?

Comment: In Silverlight the Label control changes itself after validation (the text becames red). But WPF is different.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

#### TextBlock is not a control

Even though `TextBlock` lives in the System.Windows.Controls namespace, it is not a control.  It derives directly from `FrameworkElement`. Label, on the other hand, derives from `ContentControl`. This means that `Label` can:

1. Be given a custom control template (via the `Template` property).
2. Display data other than just a string (via the `Content` property).
3. Apply a `DataTemplate` to its content (via the `ContentTemplate` property).
4. Do whatever else a `ContentControl` can do that a `FrameworkElement` cannot.

   - `Label` text is grayed out when disabled
   - `Label` supports access keys
   - `Label` is much heavier than `TextBlock`

[Source](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/)

Some more interesting reads below

- http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q4.1.ashx
- [What is the difference between the WPF TextBlock element and Label control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59099/217880)

Comment: On your second point: it is possible to bind a DateTime to a TextBlock.

Comment: I take it `TextBlock` is more performant, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 33):

Labels usually support single line text output while the TextBlock is intended for multiline text display.

For example in wpf TextBlock has a property `TextWrapping` which enables multiline input; Label does not have this.

Comment: Label has an arbitrary Content property. That can be a string, but it can also be a TextBlock (or any other control), so Labels can be multiline by using a TextBlock as the content.

Answer (score 31):

`Label` is `ContentControl` which means that you can set anything as a content for it. Absolutely anything including strings, numbers, dates, other controls, images, shapes, etc. `TextBlock` can handle only `strings`.

Comment: "other controls" includes a TextBlock, so a Label can contain wrapped text, for instance.

Answer (score 13):

Although TextBlock and Label are both used to display text, they are quite different under the covers.

=> **Label** inherits from *ContentControl*, a base class that
enables the display of almost any UI imaginable.

=> **TextBlock**, on the other hand, inherits directly from *FrameworkElement*, thus missing out on the behavior that is common to all elements inheriting from Control. 
The shallow inheritance hierarchy of TextBlock makes the control lighter weight than Label and better suited for simpler, noninteractive scenarios.

PS: However, if you want **access keys** to work or want a more flexible or graphical design, you’ll need to use Label.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most annoying feature of `TextBlock` is the implicit style lookup behavior, which is scoped to only to the closest `DataTemplate`. This is a default behavior for non `Control` xaml elements.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="Test">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Content="Test">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Yields a result of:

[image]

You can read more about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170201072114/http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html).