# Changing some user control attributes in XAML doesn't take place before running the application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a custom `UserControl` which is basically just a fancy container that has a title and some contents:

[image: My Custom <code>UserControl</code> as can be seen when code is running]
And this is how I use it in my XAML:

```
<local:MDCard Header="Some Title">
<Grid>
...
...
</Grid>
</local:MDCard>
```

The problem is that in design time (before running the code) this is what I see in the graphical XAML editor:

[image: My Custom <code>UserControl</code> as can be seen before running the code]

Notice that the title is not showing.

And this is the source code of my `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HealthAndWellBeing.MDCard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HealthAndWellBeing"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="self">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.2" BlurRadius="2"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.12" BlurRadius="8"/>
                    </Grid.Effect>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.14"/>
                        </Grid.Effect>
                        <Border Background="#FFFAFAFA" CornerRadius="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#19000000">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF616161" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </Label>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HealthAndWellBeing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MDCard.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MDCard : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MDCard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyChange(string PropertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(MDCard), new PropertyMetadata("Title"));
    }
}
```

So Why is it that when I change the text of a `Button` it can be seen in the graphical XAML editor instantly, but changing the `Header` of my custom `UserControl` can only be seen at run time?

Comment: Is the [Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5386878/3766034) displaying your Header-property properly updated after a rebuild?

Comment: no, it's just working during the run time

Comment: I think the main issue is that changing the property in design time, does not fire the PropertyChanged event

Comment: Does changing the Binding-Signature to "{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" have any effect?

Comment: @Jirajha Yes, it worked perfectly. Thank you. Can you explain your answer so I understand what happened?

Comment: `DataContext = this;` - don't do this in UserControl! you break DataContext DP inheritance. doing so fixes short-term problem (Header of UserControl can be seen at run time), but creates many more in the long run. setup bindings properly using RelativeSource

Comment: @ASh so what should I do instead?

Comment: @Amir, remove `DataContext = this;` and use bindings with RelativeSource. Also: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is usually implemented in viewmodels to notify about changes; UserControls don't need to implement INPC because they use DependencyProperties which have built-in notification mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, changing the Binding-Signature of your Label from

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF616161" Margin="10,10,10,10">
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}"/>
</Label>
```

to

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF616161" Margin="10,10,10,10">
   <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
</Label>
```

should / could solve the issue.

After all you are not trying to resolve to a property `Header` of the `ControlTemplate` you are giving to a `UserControl`, but to a Descendant of a `UserControl` class that has a `DependencyProperty` called `Header`. 
This is why you should bind to the TemplatedParent, i.e. the *actual* `UserControl` descendant.

In the case of a CustomControl you use the compile-time binding `TemplateBinding`, since you are templating this specific class.

With `UserControls` however you use `Binding`s, which are resolved at runtime via `System.Reflection`. That's why you are supposed to tell it to look for a specific parent if it is not a property of that specific class. In this case the `TemplatedParent`.

A better explanation between Binding vs TemplatedBinding however can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823547/3766034).

I can only assume that the "real" WPF runtime libraries will simply help you resolve the actual DependencyProperty - the blend (VS designer) ones won't.