# Grid of Labels Bind Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `<Grid>` set up just the way I want with each cell containing a `<Label>`.

I want this because I want the labels to have a fixed position on the screen. For example, if I have an array `{"One, "Two", "Three"}` it should go on screen as:

[ One ]***_*__*_*__*_*_** [ Two ] ***_*__*_*__*_*_** [ Three ]

If that array is `{"One, "Three"}`, I want the space for two reserved like so:

[ One ] ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** [ Three ]

The grid handles this nicely.

Now I want to bind the content of those labels to a structure in the code-behind and am struggling to get the label to bind to a specific index of the `ObservableCollection` in my code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bind like this (if your collection is defined as resource):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}, Path=[0]}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}, Path=[1]}"/>
```

and perhaps use the simpler TextBlock instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}, Path=[0]}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}, Path=[1]}"/>
```

If your collection is a property of your `DataContext` object (e.g. named `Collection`) bind like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Collection[0]}"/>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Collection[1]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain more why the TextBlock is simpler?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wpf-textblock-element-and-label-control) and perhaps [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/).

Comment: I can't seem to the get binding working. The collection is an ObservableCollection in my data context class. It's not a StaticResource.

Comment: Can the collection index be binded an enum val so there aren't magic numbers in the xaml?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you could check the [data binding how-to topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752039.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could expose properties that return the value at the indexes you want from the collection. Eg. Bind One to something like:

```
public string OneValue { get { return Collection[0]; } }
```

Comment: Interesting expose a property for each cell?

Comment: Is there anyway to have the xaml pass a param into the binding property? So I could say "{Binding Value(2)}" where 2 is the index?