# Is there a way to set the AutomationID of an object without using XAML?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I need to automate a Winform application.  How do I set the `AutomationID` (or `AutomationName`) like the the XAML in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150602.aspx)  does?

From this [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996145/is-there-any-unique-identifier-for-wpf-uielement/10814688#10814688) the answer seems to be no, unless I switch the application to a WPF application (so I can use XAML to define the controls).

I have tried this naïve approach:

```
  AutomationElement formAutomation = AutomationElement.FromHandle(this.Handle);
  formAutomation.Current.Name = "SandboxResponseDialogName";
  formAutomation.Current.ClassName = "SandboxResponseDialogClassName";
  formAutomation.Current.AutomationId = "SandboxResponseDialogID;
```

But at this point in the constructor for the control, these Automation properties have getters only; no setters.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set anything in relation to `UI Automation` in code, you need to use this:

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
```

And in your code:

```
YourObjectClass element = // just get your element.
element.SetValue(AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty, "elementAutomationID");
```

You can also use `AutomationProperties.NameProperty` for the UIAutomation Name. `AutomationProperties` contains all the properties for UIAutomation elements (setter and getter) as the name suggest.

Comment: Note that in this example `element` is not a UI Automation element (`AutomationElement`), rather a WPF control (e.g. `CheckBox`).