# How to add a line break in a label

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

How to add a line break in a label. I have a label in which i m adding a text which will result in this display

A
B
C
i have done this in WinForms c# with `Environment.NewLine` but this is not working in WPF application

Can some one tell me how can i add line break in label?

Am doing this from code behind and not `XAML`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that `Environment.NewLine` is not working in your case. Check the height of your label in XAML. When you add a Line Break then it increases the content in label and if height is not enough then you cant see that. I think you are facing this problem other wise i don't see any problem with `Environment.NewLine` :) Try adding height and tell me

Answer (score 11):

If you're fine with using [TextBlock instead of Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wpf-textblock-element-and-label-control) (you should be!), then you can do it like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="First Line"/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="Second Line"/>
</TextBlock>
```

You can do this from code behind as well (not sure why you would want to though):

```
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("First Line"));
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Second Line"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Either set your max width and let the layout mechanism work out where to put your carriage return or put some \n in there

```
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "This is a line with a carriage return";
        tb.MaxWidth = 100;
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;


        pan.Children.Add(tb);
```

in the code above, pan is just a stack panel control, you'll be adding to whatever control houses your label of course